# FNRCE0040E: E_NOT_AUTHENTICATED: The user is not authenticated. Message was: Unable to locate a login configuration

Tags: java, filenet

I am creating a web service in FileNet and I am getting below mentioned error when I am making connection with FileNet.

> FNRCE0040E: E_NOT_AUTHENTICATED: The user is not authenticated.
>   Message was: Unable to locate a login configuration at
>   com.filenet.apiimpl.core.UserPasswordToken.getSubject(UserPasswordToken.java:131)
>   at
>   com.filenet.api.util.UserContext.createSubject(UserContext.java:286)

I am using FilenetP8 and my local WAS Server version is 7.0

I have created the login modules on my local WAS server but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Show us the entire connection code you have. You can make your servername, username, password as generic like as - ceserverxyz, adminusername, adminpassword.

Comment: Make sure that you have this parameter setup in VM argument  

-Djava.security.auth.login.config = <pointing to your jaas.conf.WebSphere file>